# PostgreSQL REGEXP_REPLACE Brackets

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why would this one work:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('[GREY]', '\]', ''), '\[', '')
```

But these not:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[GREY]', '[\[\]]', '')
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[GREY]', '/[\[\]]/g', '')
```

This is the explanation from regex101.com:

```
/[\[\]]/g

Match a single character present in the list below [\[\]]
    \[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
    \] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)

Global pattern flags
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

And Match Information:

```
Match 1
    Full match  0-1 `[`
Match 2
    Full match  5-6 `]`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REGEXP_REPLACE` takes flags e.g. `g` as a separate parameter:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[GREY]', '[\[\]]', '', 'g')` returns `GREY`